# Add `git remote add usptream` to repositories but using Ansible

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an Ansible 2.9.27 and I am trying to add upstream remote for git repositories which I previously cloned with Ansible. Let's assume that already cloned repositories are located in `/home/user/Documents/github/` directory and I want to add upstream remote for them (`git remote add upstream` for each repo).

The task looks like this:

```
- name: Add remote upstream to github projects
  # TODO: how to add remote with git module?
  command: git remote add upstream git@github.com:{{ git_user }}/{{ item }}.git
  changed_when: false
  args:
    chdir: /home/user/Documents/github/{{ item }}
  loop: "{{ github_repos }}"
```

The issue is that ansible-lint doesn't like using `command` instead of `git` module:

```
WARNING  Listing 1 violation(s) that are fatal
command-instead-of-module: git used in place of git module
tasks/github.yaml:15 Task/Handler: Add remote upstream to github projects
```

What I need to do to add remote upstream for these repositories with `git` module?

Comment: The module [*git*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html) is not able to add remote. You can [*skip*](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules.html#false-positives-skipping-rules) the rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since what you want to achieve is not (yet...) taken in charge by the [`git` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html), this is a very legitimate use of `command`.

In such cases, it is possible to [silence the specific rule in ansible lint for that specific task](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules.html#false-positives-skipping-rules).

To go a bit further, your `changed_when: false` clause looks a bit like a quick and dirty fix to silence the `no-changed-when` rule and can be enhanced in conjunction with a `failed_when` clause to detect cases where the remote already exists.

Here is how I would write that task to be idempotent, documented and passing all needed lint rules:

```yaml
- name: Add remote upstream to github projects
  # Git module does not know how to add remotes (yet...)
  # Using command and silencing corresponding ansible-lint rule 
  # noqa command-instead-of-module
  command:
    cmd: git remote add upstream git@github.com:{{ git_user }}/{{ item }}.git
    chdir: /home/user/Documents/github/{{ item }}
  register: add_result
  changed_when: add_result.rc == 0
  failed_when:
    - add_result.rc != 0
    - add_result.stderr | default('') is not search("remote .* already exists")
  loop: "{{ github_repos }}"
```